# Jquery-ui-rotatable , How to make a cloned element rotatable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the code below found on 
http://www.placona.co.uk/166/javascript/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning/
http://examples.placona.co.uk/drag_drop

For drag-drop-clone .

In the same code I have tried to implement , rotatable(params) 
with jquery-ui-rotatable to the "cloned " element .

It does not function .

Where should I place the code below to make the clone rotatable
The clone here is draggable .

```
 var params = {
        start: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("Rotating started");
        },
        rotate: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("Rotating");
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("Rotating stopped");
        },
    };  $('#drag1').resizable().rotatable(params);
```

When I implement it either draggable property is lost or there are 2 clones instead of one .

Comment: can you make a JsFiddle for what you have done?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4q3379qy/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4q3379qy/1/                                                                           It is supposed to work like this http://examples.placona.co.uk/drag_drop          ,I am trying to implement :- resizable()    and rotatable()       .                                 Guide me ...

Comment: I was going though the example sample you provided and i just added these lines ...google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
     google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.3"); And it is working http://jsfiddle.net/4q3379qy/2/.

Comment: Go though this : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/138

Comment: Thanks for the response , My question was I want to implement "jquery-ui-rotatable " on the above code but since there are two different jquery used only one of them works when I integrate both ,I use noConflict() as well but that's not helping . 
Help me to implement rotate and resize in the same code .
The code which I used for rotate is :-
https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable
http://godswearhats.com/jquery-ui-rotatable/demo.html

Any method that can help me to implement rotate and resize in this http://jsfiddle.net/4q3379qy/2/ code are welcome ....